# How can I convert an Apple iOS HEIF image into JPEG?

Tags: jpeg, image-processing, heic

How can I convert an HEIF/HEIC image into a JPEG?   Maybe using ImageMagick?

Answer (score 13):

Support for reading HEIF was added to ImageMagick 7.0.7-22, you have to install it with `--with-libheif` flag.

e.g. on macOS with Homebrew: `brew install imagemagick --with-libheif`. If you have previously installed imagemagick with Homebrew, you need to uninstall it by `brew uninstall imagemagick` first.

---

One other option to convert HEIF → JPG on macOS is by using Automator. It has a "Change Type of Images" action that can do the conversion. If needed, you could have the ["to JPG" conversion available in context menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/94167/1453)

Comment: FYI.   It is possible to change the settings in your iPhone to capture photos as JPEG‘s instead of HEIF so that you don’t have to deal with their very compressed files.  Go to settings> camera> formats and choose most compatible.  Another option is to use a third-party app that saves Photos as tiff or raw and avoid compression altogether

Comment: Sure, but of course you would lose [all other perks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format#Features) in addition to the improved compression (e.g. depth maps for portrait photos) as well. Not saying either is better, but that both have drawbacks which are subject to personal preferences.

Comment: Those things are not  important to me and i prefer have complete control over my images and not let the software choose what data to delete when it compresses. If they are important to you then you can have both. The app i use can be set to save both raw and HEIF ( or JPG )

Comment: `brew reinstall` with the libheif option didn't work for me. And it seems documented as such in `brew help reinstall`: "Uninstall and then install formula (with existing install options)." However, `brew uninstall imagemagick` + `brew install imagemagick --with-libheif` worked just fine! Upvoting, but might be worth an update.

Comment: @jleverenz Thanks, fixed it. I probably tested the command after I already had installed imagemagick with libheif, so it seemed like it was working as I thought it would, while in reality it just ignored the extraneous option.

Comment: In recent versions homebrew's `imagemagick` has `libheif` inbuilt. So when you try to update an older version with `brew install imagemagick --with-libheif`, you might receive an error such as : `Error: invalid option: --with-libheif`

Simply run `brew install imagemagick` and it will install an imagemagic version that has libheif built-in.

Comment: I changed my iphone setting (as mentioned in comment above) because I didn't want HEIC -- AND my computer / phone refused to transfer the HEIF format files without the connection stopping Every. Single. Time. iPhone7, windows 7 and 10. I actually gave up on transferring files to the computer for a while. Then I found some online tips to use JPG instead. Problem solved, and I want the images in JPEG format anyway.

Answer (score 5):

1. Remove previous version of ImageMagick:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
```

2. Install base dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall 
$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxext-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev libde265-dev
$ sudo apt-get install pkg-config m4 libtool automake autoconf
```

3. Install library for reading **HEIF/HEIC** files (this step is essential):

```
$ cd /usr/src/
$ sudo wget https://github.com/strukturag/libheif/archive/v1.3.2.tar.gz
$ sudo tar -xvf v1.3.2.tar.gz
$ sudo rm v1.3.2.tar.gz
$ cd libheif-1.3.2/
$ sudo ./autogen.sh
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

4. Install ImageMagick with WEBP and HEIC support:

```
$ cd /usr/src/
$ sudo wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ sudo tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ sudo rm ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ cd ImageMagick-7.0.10-31/
$ sudo ./configure --with-heic=yes --with-webp=yes
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
$ sudo make check
```

5. Check version:

```
$ convert --version
...
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-31 Q16 x86_64 2020-10-03 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.0) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jpeg lcms lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

6. As you see *'heic'* is in the delegates list.
7. To convert single file from HEIC into JPG:

```
$ convert IMG_3288.HEIC IMG_3288.JPG
```

8. **To convert all HEIC-files in current directory into JPG:**

```
$ ls *.HEIC -1 | sed -e 's/\.HEIC$//' | xargs -I {} convert {}.HEIC {}.JPG
```

---

**OPTIONALLY:** Setting date and time of each JPG-file according to EXIF timestamp:

```
$ exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal>FileModifyDate" *.JPG
```

If you don't have **exiftool** utility you can install it by following command:

```
$ sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

---

**Usefull links:**

https://medium.com/@sanjaywrites/install-latest-version-of-imagemagick-in-ubuntu-16-04-c406ddea1973
https://gist.github.com/rjnienaber/af47fccb8410926ba7ea35f96c3b87fd

Comment: What platform/OS are these instructions for?

Comment: These instructions are for Linux with Debian package management system (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, ...)

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu/Linux**

- [filibuntu has written about HEIF software on AskUbuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/a/965306/567307) The information likely applies to other Linux distributions as well.
- **`libheif-examples`** contains command-line utilities: `heif-enc` and `heif-convert`.
- **GIMP** and **Krita** support HEIF via libheif.
- Recent Geeqie git commits have added HEIF support. It may be installed from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=geeqie%20xiota).
- **Imagemagick** can be recompiled with `libheif` support. There also do not appear to be any pre-built packages for Debian/Ubuntu.

**Windows 10**

- Windows 10 Build 17623 includes support for HEIF in the Photos app.
- The following may need to be installed:

  - [HEIF Image Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PMMSR1CGPWG)
  - [HEVC Video Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9nmzlz57r3t7) or [HEVC Video Extensions from Device Manufacturer](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9n4wgh0z6vhq)

**Online Converters**

- Google Photos and Dropbox have been reported to support HEIF.
- There are other converters, but be sure to **read their privacy policies before using them**.

Comment: i noticed today that i was able to open a `.heic` image taken on an iPhone in google classroom, so i'd assume the entire g-suite now supports it

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 have used free batch converter Converseen to convert HEIC to JPG.  Retains EXIF.   http://converseen.fasterland.net/

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, with recent ImageMagick, all I had to do from a command window was:

`magick mogrify -format jpg *.HEIC`

to convert all the HEIC files in a folder to .jpg. No batch or scripts needed.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents... I was tired of using cmd line...

I wrote a small app... if interested. it's free:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/heictojpeg/id1486256731?ls=1&mt=12

hope can be useful